# Generating threads based on a variable length array in cuda?

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda

Fist, let me explain what I am implementing. The goal of my program is to generate all possible, non-distinct combinations of a given character set on a cuda enabled GPU.  In order to parallelize the work, I am initializing each thread to a starting character.

For instance, consider the character set `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`. In this case, there will ideally be 26 threads: `characterSet[threadIdx.x] = a` for example (in practice, there would obviously be an offset to span the entire grid so that each thread has a unique identifier).

Here is my code thus far:

```
//Used to calculate grid dimensions
int* threads;
int* blocks;
int* tpb;
int charSetSize;



void calculate_grid_parameters(int length, int size, int* threads, int* blocks, int* tpb){
   //Validate input
   if(!threads || !blocks || ! tpb){
               cout <<"An error has occured: Null pointer passed to function...\nPress enter to exit...";
               getchar();
               exit(1);
   }

   //Declarations
   const int maxBlocks = 65535; //Does not change
   int maxThreads = 512; //Limit in order to provide more portability
   int dev = 0;
   int maxCombinations;
   cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;

   //Query device
   //cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, dev);
   //maxThreads = deviceProp.maxThreadsPerBlock;

   //Determine total threads to spawn
   //Length of password *  size of character set
   //Each thread will handle part of the total number of the combinations
   if(length > 3) length = 3; //Max length is 3
   maxCombinations = length * size;
   assert(maxCombinations < (maxThreads * maxBlocks));


 }
```

It is fairly basic.

I've limited length to 3 for a specific reason. The full character set, `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 !\"#$&'()*+-.:;<>=?@[]^_{}~|` is, I believe, 92 characters. This means for a length of 3, there are 778,688 possible non-distinct combinations. If it were length 4, than it would be roughly 71 million, and the maximum number of threads for my GPU is about 69 million (in one dimension). Furthermore, these combinations have already been generated in a file that will be read into an array and then delegated a specific initializing thread.

This leads me to my problem.

The maximum number of blocks on a cuda GPU (for 1-d) is 65,535. Each of those blocks (on my gpu) can run 1024 threads in one dimension.  I've limited it to 512 in my code for portability purposes (this may be unnecessary). Ideally, each block should run 32 threads or a multiple of 32 threads in order to be efficient. The issue I have is how many threads I need. Like I said above, if I am using a full character set of length 3 for the starting values, this necessitates 778,688 threads. This happens to be divisible by 32, yielding 24,334 blocks assuming each block runs 32 threads. However, if I run the same character set with length two, I am left with 264.5 blocks each running 32 threads.

Basically, my character set is variable and the length of the initializing combinations is variable from 1-3.

If I round up to the nearest whole number, my offset index, `tid = threadIdx.x + ....` will be accessing parts of the array that simply do not exist.

How can I handle this problem in such a way that is will still run efficiently and not spawn unnecessary threads that could potentially cause memory problems?

Any constructive input is appreciated.

Comment: Spawning threads takes time too - so you want to trade off number of threads vs amount of code each thread produces. There are many ways to make generating permutations / combinations faster - brute force multi threading should be used once the others have been explored.

Comment: @Floris I agree, I've looked for quite awhile in regards to generating permutations and combinations faster. For instance, my favorite are combanadic and factoradic methods. The problem, though, was that they produce distinct combinations/permutations. `ABB` is equal to `BBA` in those methods. This program is a project of mine to try and  bruteforce a md5 hashed password. That being the case, I need non-distinct passwords. There may be better methods, but I am curious how to implement this method.

Comment: Stack overflow tends to frown upon questions that ask "please help me develop a brute force password cracking program". At any rate I think the time to generate passwords will be small compared to the time to see if the hash matches. If you think about it you can just "count in n-ary", where n is the number of distinct characters. It is just like regular numbers. Once you have 0 - 99, you can add '0', '1', '2' etc in front for the next 900 combinations / permutations; then do it again for the next 9000, etc.. So you re-use the old ones as you add a new one in front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've posted doesn't seem to do anything significant and includes no cuda code.

Your question appears to be this:

> How can I handle this problem in such a way that is will still run efficiently and not spawn unnecessary threads that could potentially cause memory problems?

It's common practice when launching a kernel to "round up" to the nearest increment of threads, perhaps 32, perhaps some multiple of 32, so that an integral number of blocks can be launched.  In this case, it's common practice to include a thread check in the kernel code, such as:

```
__global__ void mykernel(.... int size){
  int idx=threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;

  if (idx < size){
    //main body of kernel code here
  }
}
```

In this case, `size` is your overall problem size (the number of threads that you actually want).  The overhead of the additional threads that are doing nothing is normally not a significant performance issue.

Comment: Yes, my code doesn't do anything significant...I wanted to at least show I started something. It is a start to determine the proper parameters of the kernel launch. Thanks, that is a good solution to my problem.